# Google ReCaptcha is not validating: Magento 2.2.9

Tags: magento2, recaptcha, mageplaza

I´ve got the Google ReCaptcha extension from Mageplaza and got the v2 keys. The extension is enabled and it is displayed on the forms accurately, but neither visible nor invisible is validating. The form can be submitted and the reCaptcha is not validating. [image]

Comment: Your Magento version?

Comment: Please check in log or exception. Is there any kind of error while submitting the form?

Comment: It must show some js error in browser console. Kindly check that error and paste over here so that i can suggest further what can be the issue.

Comment: There is the console, and the Magento version is 2.2.9